# FFT and Convolution

Tags: polynomials

Suppose we are asked to find convolution of two polynomials, actually not necessarily convolution it is product of two polynomials. Is there two different formula for multiplication via FFT? One having /N and another not? I am a bit confused, it would be great help if any one could clear it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have polynomials of degree N-1 with N coefficients, then the product will have degree 2N-2 with 2N-1 coefficients. So you have to use the FFT with length 2N or larger. Conceptually, you first apply the inverse transform to the factors to get the values on the unit circle. Then you multiply the values and do a forward transform to compute the interpolating polynomial.

The last step requires division by 2N after FFT to finish the interpolation. Quick check for reasonableness: Let both factors and thus the polynomial be the constant 1, interpreted as polynomials of degree N-1 resp. 2N-1. Then the values obtained in the inverse transforms are all 1, as it should be. The forward transform in the second step will produce the sum of all values, that is 2N, in the constant coefficient, and zero in all other coefficients. To get the correct product, you have to divide by 2N.

Please elaborate on the differences of the two methods. The only alternative method I know is Schönhages based on the Schönhage-Strassen integer multiplication. It translates both factors into very long big integers and recovers the coefficients of the product from the product of the big integers. The big integer multiplication is achieved with a number theoretic variant of the FFT, using roots of -1 in the remainder class ring of moduli 2^(m*2^k)+1.